# In git log, looking for a more useful variant of --first-parent

Tags: git, github

I have a git project where a contributor came back after a long absence, and did an ugly merge rather a pull before his commit.

As a result, the project history now looks like:

```
e6a1272 * Current tip
3750671 *   Another (somewhat less ugly) merge
        |\  
a5df959 | * Progress...
bb55ba3 * |   Ugly merge.  Catch up on weeks of progress, plus add one line
        |\ \  
        | |/  
67d18aa | * Many more commits...
937909a | * ...
094c77a | * Progress...
3ac93c1 | * Progress...
cbca9b4 * | Progress...
        |/  
1055f06 * An old commit, weeks ago
449cb7c * Another old commit
...
```

To be fair, it's not absolutely terrible but:

- It has spider tracks in what should be a clean linear history
- github shows thousands of lines of diff for `bb55ba3` relative to `1055f06`, rather than the three lines of real changes from `67d18aa`. Within the github interface, there is no easy way to see what this commit really does.
- Similarly, `git log --first-parent` elides most of the history
- Mostly, it just offends my sensibilities, since I like clean histories.

I've already tutored the contributor re how to avoid this problem in the future, but my question is:

Is there any way to tell github and `--first-parent` which branch to follow, without rewriting history?  Anything else I can do to make this cleaner, without rewriting history?

(That said, I probably could rewrite history, since the project is private, with only a handful of people who can see it.  So, maybe that's the best option? Or am I being too compulsively neat even worrying about this?)

Oh, and a related question: Similar problems are likely to bite me in the future. Are the any git hooks I can setup that will prevent this and similar issues?

Comment: I personally also like a clean looking linear history, but linear history is not necessarily better. I would suggest reading [this blog post](https://medium.com/@fredrikmorken/why-you-should-stop-using-git-rebase-5552bee4fed1), which advocates that you shouldn't use `git rebase` or `git merge --squash` at all, just to see some other perspectives.

Comment: Why are merges considered ugly?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "smart `--first-parent`" that can use the 2nd parent instead in this case.

Comment: Thanks @alderath, that blog post was excellent. I realize that my issue here is more subtle. It's not the merge itself that bothered me; it is the fact that the merge was done "backwards", with the contributor merging the full history into his change, rather than vice versa.  Or. I guess, maybe the issue is simply that neither github nor git --graph is clever enough to realize which side of the merge is the dominant one.  Of my four issues in the OP, the key one is the second: that the tools emphasize the wrong branch and don't show a useful diff.